# bash: regex extraction

Tags: regex, linux, bash, extract

I have this string

```
export FOO="/home/u4589/something.git"
```

How can I extract something from this string?

In this case I want to extract the number after the letter u.

Comment: Did you look at any of the Q/A returned when searching for `[bash] extract regex from string`? Approx 50 items. Please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash only

```
FOO="/home/u4589/something.git"
FOO=${FOO%/*}
echo ${FOO#*u}
4589
```

Answer (score 0):

This a very specific requirement. And solution you may get may not work for a slightly different path. You should first check the the basics of regex

However the solution for the particular problem you've presented is

```
echo "$FOO" | sed -E 's#^.*/u([[:digit:]]*)/.*$#\1#'
4589
```